# How do i keep smpp 3.4 connection active without timeout

Tags: go, smpp

I have implemented this golang smpp package (https://github.com/fiorix/go-smpp) in my platform. After sending few SMS, i get a timeout and the sending stops. i.e Sending bulk sms messages to 5,000 contacts, only 500 contacts receive the message then there is a timeout. Kindly help with your suggestions on ow i can sustain the sending without the timeout.

Some of my smpp settings are;

EnquireLink:        time.Duration(120) * time.Second,
EnquireLinkTimeout: time.Duration(122) * time.Second,

Comment: Is this specific to the package or rate limited at the server side?

Comment: @MelvinDavis it's not specific to the package

Comment: Whenever you see a timeout, why don't reinitiate the connection and wait for a few seconds and continue sending the messages

Comment: @MelvinDavis, i can reinitiate the connection, but some messages have no response ID, making it hard to update on their statuses

Comment: You can store the messages with some integer ids on a  map. Once the connection is reinitiated loop through the map and pick the pending ones. Better use database to store.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect with SMPP as client to some SMPP server, the server will impose a idle timeout on your connection and drop the connection. From your side, you must ensure your EnquireLink is shorter than what the server expects, so your client will keep the connection busy and server won't drop it.

I would go for 10 seconds... SMPP is very light protocol (compared to HTTP etc) and one EnquireLink message every 10 seconds is not going to hurt.

I believe EnquireLink setting is how frequent you send EnquireLink and EnquireLinkTimeout is how long you allow the for the server to respond to it - which could be much shorter. So try:
EnquireLink: 10 seconds
EnquireLinkTimeout: 2seconds